# Java extend generic class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a generic class:

```
public class RangeSeekBar<T extends Number> extends ImageView {
    public RangeSeekBar(T absoluteMinValue, T absoluteMaxValue, Context context) throws IllegalArgumentException {
```

that I am trying to extend:

```
class MinMax extends RangeSeekBar<Integer> {
    MinMax(Integer absoluteMinValue, Integer absoluteMaxValue, Context context) {
        super.RangeSeekBar( absoluteMinValue, absoluteMaxValue, context )
    }
```

but Eclipse says (on super.RangeSeekBar constructor call): The method RangeSeekBar(Integer, Integer, Context) is undefined for the type RangeSeekBar

How should it be written ?

Comment: I think that you can't call `super.RangeSeekBar` because it's a generic class without any type. You define it a type when you create your subclass. Why do you want to use `super`?

Comment: `super.RangeSeekBar` is not a valid constructor call, it should be `super`

Comment: doesn't super() it self call the constructor on RangeSeekBar

Comment: @DevZer0 it calls the constructor of the super class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using wrong syntax calling super class's constructor. You should say

`super( absoluteMinValue, absoluteMaxValue, context )`

Comment: Its also good to explain `super.RangeSeekBar` will try to find a method `RangeSeekBar` in super class.